# rails-installer.sh runs fine but ruby, irb, rails command "not found" (UB12.04)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I ran rails-installer.sh on ubuntu 12.04. The scripts reports that ruby and gems and rails all installed without problem.

However, when I try:

```
ruby -v
rails -v
etc.
```

They all report "command not found".

I am new to linux... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Arghh.. never mind.  sometimes the simple things really do elude me.

The path change do not take effect until you start a new shell.

All is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for every *.bat file inside the C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin folder which contains "emachnic" paths, and replace the whole content of them with this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
ECHO.This version of Ruby has not been built with support for Windows 95/98/Me.
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"%~dp0ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

For more details refer the link.
https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/issues/70